# How can I create this figure title in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, latex, title

I want to combine Latex, numbers, and Tex into the title of a figure using the following (`beta_b` and `lambda` are defined variables):

```
title(['$\overline{\beta}=$' num2str(beta_b) 'TE0 , \lambda=' num2str(lambda*1e6) ' \mum'], 'interpreter','latex');
```

But it doesn't display properly. What's the problem?

Comment: @Marcelo: Not really. MATLAB and Latex questions are valid on SO.

Comment: @gnovice: Fair point on MATLAB. But how is a LaTeX question relevant, especially one that involves no programming?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't combine Latex *and* Tex in a [title](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/title.html). You have to use one or the other (i.e. whichever one you set for the [`'Interpreter'` property](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/text_props.html#Interpreter)). The following will work:

```
title(['$\overline{\beta}=$' num2str(beta_b) ...
       ' TEO , $\lambda=$' num2str(lambda*1e6) ' $\mu$m'],...
      'Interpreter','latex');
```

Note that you have to include `$` on either side of `\lambda` and `\mu` so they can be interpreted properly. The `$` also has to go between the `\mu` and `m`, otherwise it gets tripped up on the `\mum`.

Comment: @gnovie: On an unrelated note, do you think MATLAB has a shot of winning this code golf tournie?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365487/code-golf-build-me-an-arc/3369332#3369332

Comment: @Jacob: It's possible. I've done well in a couple of them using MATLAB. I'll try to take a look and see if it can be trimmed down more. ;)

Comment: Thanks! The Perl code's been massively trimmed so it's quite hard now!