# Matlab question: Displaying math equations in the title of a plot using (la)tex

Tags: matlab

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I create this figure title in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371039/how-can-i-create-this-figure-title-in-matlab)

I would like to write down math equations in the m-file in the plot such as

let us say I define

```
d = 1;
```

in the MATLAB code. I want to plot with the title such as

```
title('The Solution of Equations $f(x,t)=0$ when the Parameter is %d')
```

Please advise.

Comment: You already asked this question. Please explain how this is different other than writing weird function symbols inside the title.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666651/matlab-question-quote-value-of-variables-in-the-tile-of-a-plot/6666691#6666691

Comment: Yes the question is how to use tex in the title of a plot of matlab.

Comment: @aardvarkk: Although it looks like the previous question at first glance, it is nonetheless different

Comment: @Jacob Putting "math equations" in the title of a plot and putting TeX code in the title are two very different things. The question didn't state anything about TeX until I asked. I agree that it's now a valid question.

Answer (score 0):

```
title(text('Interpreter','latex',...
'String','The solution is: $$\int_0^x\!\int_y dF(u,v)$$',...
'Position',[.5 .5],...
'FontSize',16))
```

Comment: I think there may be versioning problems with the LaTeX intepreter. In my version (7.1!), `text` is automatically interpreted as TeX. So, as far as I can tell, `title('The Solution of Equations f(x,t)=0 when the Parameter is %d')` is already correct?

Comment: Actually I want to use more complex equations that cannot be handled without tex.

Comment: How does it handle quoting the value of variables?

Comment: I am using version 7.6, I know that the default interpreter setting is to latex, but I have found if I don't explicitly state it, it will have issues when I try and do things like insert an equation into a string. Also you would need to use the create a math environment to use things like \int. I have not been able to do this without setting the Interpreter to 'latex'.