# How do I create this matrix in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I'm attempting to solve the [Code Golf: Build Me an Arc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365487/code-golf-build-me-an-arc/3369332#3369332) problem. My solution's not bad, but I figure, there's a simpler way to do it. Does anybody know how to generate an `nxn` matrix like this, given `n`? I spent 57 characters getting it!

```
 3     0     0     0     2     0     0     0     1
 0     3     0     0     2     0     0     1     0
 0     0     3     0     2     0     1     0     0
 0     0     0     3     2     1     0     0     0
 4     4     4     4     8     8     8     8     8
 0     0     0     5     6     7     0     0     0
 0     0     5     0     6     0     7     0     0
 0     5     0     0     6     0     0     7     0
 5     0     0     0     6     0     0     0     7
```

I would like to beat some of these [matrices](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/f16-5872.html#f16-6070) into shape.

#### Update:

This is how I get it now.

```
%%# Create the grid
[X Y]=meshgrid(-r:r);
%%# Compute the angles in degrees
T=atan2(-Y,X)/pi*180;
%%# Get all the angles
T=T+(T<=0)*360;
```

As you can see, I don't need most of the entries in `T`.

Comment: After copying the text to Excel and applying conditional formatting, I see the pattern. There are eight straight lines, all originating from the edge and ending at the origin, filled with the integers 1, 2, ..., 8, respectively. The first line starts at the upper-right corner, and the (n+1)th line starts at a pseudoangle of pi/4 from the nth line.

Comment: Yes, it's related to the code golf link I posted. This will be used to draw sectors.

Comment: I haven't been able to find a way to create the array using specialized arrays. However, since this is code golf: Why do you transform everything to degrees? It should be sufficient to use multiples of `pi`. In other words, you can divide all angles by 180 (or 45, if you prefer), and save lots of characters.

Comment: 1) The input is in degrees so it saves characters using it directly  instead of converting `w` and `x` (in the golf solution) to radians 2)|'45'|<|'pi/4'|

Comment: I'm confused. When I run your code I don't get the output you show.

Comment: @Geoff: Divide by 45 and keep the integers (let the rest be 0).

Comment: `[X Y]=meshgrid(-r:r);T=atan2(-Y,X)/pi+2*(Y>=0)` is 47 characters, needs to be multiplied by 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is related to a Code Golf question, consider:

```
[X Y]=meshgrid(r:-1:-r,-r:r);
T=180+atan2(Y,X)*180/pi;
```

which would save you 3 characters...

Answer (score 0):

Listed in this posted is a one-liner solution code with [`bsxfun`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) that saves us from using temporary variables as it internally does the `expansion` that `meshgrid` does explicitly and at the sametime give us the ability to mention a mathematical operation to be performed between the two inputs listed inside `bsxfun`. With these internal operations, a `bsxfun` based solution seems perfect for such a code-golf thing with **`43 characters`** solution for the stated problem -

```
T=180+bsxfun(@atan2,[-r:r]',r:-1:-r)*180/pi
```